# Python: Using a variable name as a dictionary key value while assignment

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, key

I'm trying to assign a certain value from a function to a variable, but in a way that I do not specify the variable name during assignment, rather a dictionary key that has as value that variable name.

```
def func1():
        return 'Function without argument is working'
def func2(a,b,c,d,e):
        return a+b+c+d+e
def func3(a,b,c,d):
        return a+b+c+d

function_list={0:{'func':func1},
               1:{'func':func2,'args':('Function',' with',' argumants',' is',' working')},
               2:{'func':func3,'args':('Variable',' takes',' function',' value'),'var':result}}

for i in range(3):
        f=function_list[i]
        print f
        if 'var' in f:
                print 'function type 3'
                f['var']=f['func'](*f['args'])
                print 'Result is: ',result
        elif 'args' in f:
                print 'function type 2'
                print f['func'](*f['args'])
        else:
                print 'function type 1'
                print f['func']()
```

- 1st item in the dictionary will be just a simple function, without arguments
- 2nd item in the dictionary is a function with arguments, no problem running this...
- 3rd item in the dictionary is again a function with arguments, but also a variable name that should take the value returned from '***func3***'

So in the if statement ***f['var']=f'func'*** will take the result from ***func3*** but it will not be passed in the variable ***result***, rather this will be replaced as the '***var***' key value.

Could someone help me out, to modify this code so that the ***result*** variable will take in the value from ***func3***?

Thanks a lot, Alex

PS: I tried to modify the first if statement, in the following manner, but without any good result.
The ***result*** variable does not take the value of from ***func3***

```
 if 'var' in f:
            print 'function type 3'
            for key,variable in f.iteritems():
                if key=='var':
                    print 'Found key, value should be: ', f['func'](*f['args'])
                    globals()[variable]=f['func'](*f['args'])
                    print 'variable is',variable
```

SOLVED:
Managed to solve the problem, by introducing an additional key in the indexed dictionary.t
They key for the new item is also the name of the variable I need.

```
function_list={0:{'func':func1},
               1:{'func':func2,'args':('Function',' with',' argumants',' is',' working')},
               2:{'func':func3,'args':('Variable',' takes',' function',' value'),'var':'','result':'var'}}

for i in range(3):
        f=function_list[i]
        print f
        if 'var' in f:
                print 'function type 3'
                for key,variable in f.iteritems():
                    if variable=='var':
                        print 'Found key, value should be: ', f['func'](*f['args'])
                        globals()[key]=f['func'](*f['args'])
                        print 'variable is',key       
        elif 'args' in f:
                print 'function type 2'
                print f['func'](*f['args'])
        else:
                print 'function type 1'
                print f['func']()
```

Comment: Is **f['var']=f'func'** a typo? Do you mean `f['var'] = f['func']`?

Comment: Actually: f['var']=f['func'](*f['args'])

Comment: In `function_list`, the key `1` appears two times... Do you mean `0`, `1` and `2`?

Comment: Yes, the function list dictionary, contains three dictionaries with  0, 1, 2 as key.